# Orchard off the shelf and no joy

Tags: orchardcms

Just grabbed the latest .zip release of the orchard CMS from http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/view/65184 and have opened this via VS2010 by pointing
at the extracted folder.

When I attempt to compile I get the following error:

The type or namespace name 'Blogs' does not exist in the namespace 'Orchard' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either:

- download the recommended download and run that directly without compiling. It simply does not have what's necessary to recompile everything. It only knows how to dynamically compile modules and themes at runtime.
- download the full source code and compile that in VS

If you are going to use VS, I highly recommend you use the full source code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's in that zip but if this is ur first look at orchard, try using webmatrix.  It's fairly painless.

Orchard is not a conventional mvc app. It has a core needs to be compiled but the modules are compiled at runtime. If the core isn't compiled in that zip you'll need to open the project from the sln file in visual studio. If it is compiled you might need to setup the web directory as a virtual directory in iis.

I found it easier to familiarize myself with orchard in webmatrix first. There is enough in that to keep u busy for a bit!

Hope that helps

Comment: Kind of annoyed that Webmatrix factors into the process at all. Grabbed the source build from Codeplex and am starting from there.